# FOSUserBundle - BadCredentialsException

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use **FOSUserBundle** to provide user authorization and registration. Everything works fine, but when I try to log in using a non-existing username, I get this error:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException'
with message 'Bad credentials' in
/var/www/OnTheWay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/OnTheWay/app/cache/dev/classes.php(120): session_start()
#1 /var/www/OnTheWay/app/cache/dev/classes.php(198): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
#2 /var/www/OnTheWay/app/cache/dev/classes.php(498): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->getBag('attributes')
```

I've tried finding a solution, but I didn't get any results.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

From the [Github changelog](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Changelog.md):

> [BC break] The FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig template now
>   receives an AuthenticationException in the error variable rather than
>   an error message.

To fix the issue, you need to update your custom login template `login.html.twig`:

From:

```
{% if error %}
    ... {{ error|trans }} ...
{% endif %}
```

To:

```
{% if error %}
    ... {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }} ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks a million times